# HTML5 web app to upload images to server

Tags: android, iphone, html, photo-upload

Is it possible to create an HTML5 application/website for mobile(android, Iphones, IPad) which will allow user to upload pictures from their mobile to server?

I am not looking for pure app, it could be a website hosted on any server.

*Though, I am looking for my ASP.NET application but I believe that if I get solution for HTML, that would also be fine because I heard that mobile safari doesn't support upload in IPhone*

Comment: iPhone/iPad can't upload from Safari, you need an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such a thing as an HTML5 File API, but, no, this is not possible on most mobile devices (and not possible in some desktop environments, including IE, either).

Android allows this in the most recent iteration (3.0), but the Safari browser in iOS doesn't have access to any filesystem from which to pull assets. For example, consider that you can't even add an image to an email except from the Camera/Library application itself.

[Check out caniuse.com](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aUv-Ffald6CEJ%3acaniuse.com/fileapi%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) for a full picture of compatibility.

Comment: iOS 6 will support html5 file uploads and access to the device's camera. http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ios-6-beta-1-html5-native

Comment: What a helpful answer. Why everybody doesnt answer questions like this? Just google it!:D

Answer (score 4):

iOS 6 supports uploading a file if it's implemented using HTML 5.

Just add the usual `<input type="file" />` tag to your form.  When user's click this they'll be prompted to either select an existing photo or take a new photo with the camera.

Comment: Does Android have similar HTML5 photo upload support?

Comment: Re Android - Jelly Bean has this facility too - just tested `input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"`.